# How to call API Gateway with Cognito Credentials through retrofit2 on Android?

Tags: android, aws-sdk, retrofit2, amazon-cognito, aws-api-gateway

I use `retrofit2` in my android apps for any http/rest call. Now I need to call an api generated with [Amazon AWS API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/).

The AWS documentation [say](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html#how-to-generate-sdk-android) I should generate the client code throw the API Gateway console and use the class `ApiClientFactory` to build the request:

```
ApiClientFactory factory = new ApiClientFactory();

// Use CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider to provide AWS credentials
// for the ApiClientFactory
AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
        context,          // activity context
        "identityPoolId", // Cognito identity pool id
        Regions.US_EAST_1 // region of Cognito identity pool
};

factory.credentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);

// Create an instance of your SDK (this should come from the generated code).
final MyApiClient client = factory.build(MyApiClient.class);

// Invoke a method (e.g., 'parentPath1Get(param1,body)') exposed by your SDK. 
// Here the method's return type is OriginalModel.
OriginalModel output = client.parentPath1Get(param1,body);

// You also have access to your API's models.
OriginalModel myModel = new OriginalModel();
myModel.setStreetAddress(streetAddress);
myModel.setCity(city);
myModel.setState(state);
myModel.setStreetNumber(streetNumber);
myModel.setNested(nested);
myModel.setPoBox(poBox);
```

Instead I would like to define the API like I would with `retrofit`: with an interface I write, connect it to RxJava, OkHttp etc...

My question is: how can I sign the retrofit requests with Cognito Identity Provider?

Comment: I ended up using the AWS SDK directly and wrapping it in Rx Observables on my own. The answer from Jack Kohn is not wrong but it's not really an answer either, it's just pointing in the right direction if you want to implement it on your own.

Comment: so i am trying to hook up android with API gateway, but how or where did you get/create the class `MyApiClient` ?

Comment: the name depends on your services. Theres a generator / export from the web console for api gateway. I did not use this method though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Created an OkHttp interceptor based on @thanhbinh84 answer. Give it a try: https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor

Comment: Marking as accepted answer without really testing this because I currently do not have this need anymore and I haven't got the time to test it. I'll revoke my accepted answer if someone try it and find it not working / I'd appreciate people confirming it does work too!

Answer (score 6):

It took me several days to figure out how to make it work. Don't know why they don't point out the class instead of dozen of document pages. There are 4 steps in total, you must call in worker thread, I am using Rxjava but you can use AsyncTask instead:

```
    Observable.create((Observable.OnSubscribe<String>) subscriber -> {
//Step 1: Get credential, ask server team for Identity pool id and regions            
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
                this, // Context
                "Identity Pool ID", // Identity Pool ID
                Regions.US_EAST_1 // Region
            );

//Step 2: Get these 3 three keys, test with postman v4.9.3 to see if identity is correct  
            String identityId = credentialsProvider.getIdentityId();
            Log.show("identityId = " + identityId);

            String AccessKey = credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSAccessKeyId();
            String SecretKey = credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getAWSSecretKey();
            String SessionKey = credentialsProvider.getCredentials().getSessionToken();

            Log.show("AccessKey = " + AccessKey);
            Log.show("SecretKey = " + SecretKey);
            Log.show("SessionKey = " + SessionKey);
//Step 3: Create an aws requets and sign by using AWS4Signer class
            AmazonWebServiceRequest amazonWebServiceRequest = new AmazonWebServiceRequest() {
            };

            ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration();

            String API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME = "execute-api";

            Request request = new DefaultRequest(amazonWebServiceRequest,API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
            request.setEndpoint(URI.create("YOUR_URI"));
            request.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.GET);

            AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
            signer.setServiceName(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
            signer.setRegionName(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1).getName());
            signer.sign(request, credentialsProvider.getCredentials());

            Log.show("Request header " + request.getHeaders().toString());
//Step 4: Create new request with authorization headers 

            OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
            List<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

            for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet())
            {
                key.add(entry.getKey());
                value.add(entry.getValue());
            }

            try {
                okhttp3.Request request2 = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
                        .url("Your_url") // remember to add / to the end of the url, otherwise the signature will be different 
                        .addHeader(key.get(0), value.get(0))
                        .addHeader(key.get(1), value.get(1))
                        .addHeader(key.get(2), value.get(2))
                        .addHeader(key.get(3), value.get(3))

                        .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .build();
                Response response = null;

                response = httpClient.newCall(request2).execute();
                String body = response.body().string();
                Log.show("response " + body);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.show("error " + e);
            }

            subscriber.onNext(identityId);

        }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.show("Throwable = " + e.getMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(String s) {

            }
        });
```

The key here is the AWS4Signer class does 4 steps as documented [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html?shortFooter=true), you don't need to build one from scratch. In order to use AWS4Signer and AmazonWebServiceRequest, you need to import aws sdk in gradle:

```
compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.3.9'
```

Comment: I've no chance to test this now, but aside from needing a bit of cleanup seems like the right solution :) I'll get back to it when I can, thanks. (in the meanwhile I did without retrofit but using their SDK directly because I didn't have time to spend on it)

Comment: @DanieleSegato, I might switch to AWS SDK later, I will need your help that time. :)

Comment: It's easier to do, less clean then retrofit tough (aka = more boilerplate) :-)

Comment: Getting Host header as null

Comment: You saved so much of my time! thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The signature process is documented here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html

But you could probably try to reuse some of the code from the core runtime package that the default API Gateway client depends on. There may be libraries out there already for signing requests of type RxJava or OkHttp since the signature process is well-known.

Comment: thanks. I'll need this next month probably. I hope someone will post more details, a library or something in the meanwhile. If not I'll do it myself starting from the link you gave