# Android, OkHttp, AWS4Signer, aws-api-gateway - "Missing Authentication Token"

Tags: android, aws-api-gateway, okhttp

i am trying to sign a http request to aws api gateway in android using okhttp. i have more or less used the code in this stackoverflow question [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737058/how-to-call-api-gateway-with-cognito-credentials-through-retrofit2-on-android/42106050)

i use CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider() to get a credentialsProvider object. i then use getCredentials() to get the credentials. i then use the following: credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId(), credentials.getAWSSecretKey() and credentials.getSessionToken() to get the necessary keys and token. i use them in postman and am able to successfully execute the api gateway.

the request fails in android using okhttp, returning a code 403 with the message "Missing Authentication Token".

this is how i prepare the request: i build a DefaultRequest object, setting the endpoint and httpmethod. i then use AWS4Signer to sign the request, passing the credentials object as the signer.sign(defaultRequest, credentials) parameter.

i get a map of headers by calling getHeaders() on the defaultRequest. i create two lists, one called key for the key and one called value for the value. i then loop through the map, loading the keys and corresponding values into the two lists.

i then build my okhttp request as follows:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(my ApiEndPoint)
                    .addHeader(key.get(0), value.get(0))
                    .addHeader(key.get(1), value.get(1))
                    .addHeader(key.get(2), value.get(2))
                    .addHeader(key.get(3), value.get(3))
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .post(body)
                    .build();
```

i notice the following:

in the headers map, key **x-amz-security-token** has a value ....ending in *hKADF87VZ44w9IvZ1gU=*

printing out the okhttp request, the key **x-amz-security-token** has a value .... ending in *hKADF87VZ44w9IvZ1gU\u003d*

the = is replaced by \u003d, could this be the problem? if so, how to prevent this?

otherwise, any help in solving this problem will be greatly appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

managed to solve the problem. seems that assigning the headers to the OkHttp request was the problem. so here's my code:

i first get AWSSessionCredentials credentials. then:

```
   AmazonWebServiceRequest amazonWebServiceRequest = new AmazonWebServiceRequest() {
    };

    String API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME = "execute-api";

    com.amazonaws.Request requestAws = new DefaultRequest(amazonWebServiceRequest, API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
```

you can use either the service endpoint:

```
URI uri = URI.create("https://apigateway.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com");
```

or your api url (the invoke url for api as per Api Gateway console Stages option (The deployed api)):

```
String invokeUrl = "https://xxxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/yyy/zzzzz";

//      using the invoke url
    URI uri = URI.create(invokeUrl);
    requestAws.setEndpoint(uri);
    requestAws.setResourcePath(invokeUrl);
    requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);
```

now sign the request

```
AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
    signer.setServiceName(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
    signer.setRegionName(Region.getRegion(Regions.EU_WEST_1).getName());
    signer.sign(requestAws, credentials);
```

get the headers

```
//        get map of headers
    Map<String, String> headers = requestAws.getHeaders();
//        create objects for the headers to add manually in OkHttp request builder
    String x_date = null;
    String x_token = null;
    String authorization = null;
//get and assign values
    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey().equals("x-amz-security-token")) {
            x_token = entry.getValue();
        }
        if (entry.getKey().equals("X-Amz-Date")) {
            x_date = entry.getValue();
        }
        if (entry.getKey().equals("Authorization")) {
            authorization = entry.getValue();
        }
    }
```

build the OkHttp request:

```
Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(invokeUrl)
            .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .addHeader("X-Amz-Date", x_date)
            .addHeader("x-amz-security-token", x_token)
            .addHeader("Authorization", authorization)
            .post(body)
            .build();
```

now make your OkHttp call.

hope this is helpful to someone.

Comment: Hi @Clive Sargeant. I need to know does AWS charge you on using its methods like AWS4Signer, and AmazonWebServiceRequest?

Comment: Hi @Clive, Could you please help Hod did you add a header for X-Amz-Content-Sha256. I'm able to send the request. However, I receive a 403 error code. Could you please help