# Calling AWS API - Signature, Authentication Header - using OkHTTP in android

Tags: java, android, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to sign a HTTP request to AWS API in android using OkHTTP. I have used code from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38737058/how-to-call-api-gateway-with-cognito-credentials-through-retrofit2-on-android/42106050). The documentation of AWS was not at all helpful. I am very confused. This is the only code I have found so far which is easy to understand and implement. But it is also not working for my problem. I am not passing any data with API its just simple API which I have to call and receive a message.

**My Code**

```
AWSCredentials credentials =  new BasicAWSCredentials(access_key_id.trim(), secret_access_key.trim());
String API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME = "execute-api";

Request requestAws = new DefaultRequest(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
URI uri = URI.create(url);
requestAws.setEndpoint(uri);
requestAws.setResourcePath(url);
requestAws.setHttpMethod(HttpMethodName.POST);

AWS4Signer signer = new AWS4Signer();
signer.setServiceName(API_GATEWAY_SERVICE_NAME);
signer.setRegionName("us-east-2");
signer.sign(requestAws, credentials);

OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
Map<String, String> headers = requestAws.getHeaders();
List<String> key = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> value = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : headers.entrySet()) {
   key.add(entry.getKey());
   value.add(entry.getValue());
}

okhttp3.Request request = new okhttp3.Request.Builder()
.url(url)
.addHeader(key.get(0), value.get(0))
.addHeader(key.get(1), value.get(1))
.addHeader(key.get(2), value.get(2))
.build();

Response response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
```

**Error I get**

```
{"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/**2nd last part of url ***/**last part of url ***/\n\nhost:***.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-date:20210306T082609Z\n\nhost;x-amz-date\***signature***'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20210306T082609Z\n20210306/us-east-2/execute-api/aws4_request\n***signature***'\n"}
```

Its a simple code, but I cant find any issue. Server error is also not helpful.

From server side i am not using any content-type thats why i have not passed this in header. can this be an issue? I also think there is some issue with my requesAws.

May be there is issue in this line. I dont know what exactly this mean so I have passed same API url in it as in referred code.

```
requestAws.setResourcePath(url);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't recommend writing your own SigV4 signer. Instead, try pulling one is as a library dependency.

Try [babbel's OkHttp signer](https://github.com/babbel/okhttp-aws-signer):

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.babbel:okhttp-aws-signer:1.0.1'
}
```

```kotlin
val signer = OkHttpAwsV4Signer("us-east-1", "execute-api")

val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor { chain ->
        val original = chain.request()
        val signed = signer.sign(original, accessKeyId, accessKey)
        chain.proceed(signed)
    }
    .build()
```

Or [Ghedeon's](https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor):

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://dl.bintray.com/ghedeon/maven"
    }
}

...

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.ghedeon:aws-interceptor:0.6'
}
```

```kotlin
val interceptor = AwsInterceptor(credentialsProvider, serviceName, region)
 
val okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(interceptor)
    .build()
```

The latter [uses the AWS Android SDK under the hood](https://github.com/Ghedeon/AwsInterceptor/blob/master/aws-interceptor/build.gradle#L7). You could supply `AWSMobileClient.getInstance()` for the `credentialsProvider` argument, if you're using Amazon Cognito.

```kotlin
val okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
    .addInterceptor(AwsInterceptor(
        AWSMobileClient.getInstance(), "execute-api", "us-east-1"
    ))
    .build()
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this and will let you know.

Comment: Hi. @Jameson. Do i need to add any android SDK generated from AWS, in my app? or we can use the above library directly in app?

Comment: Thank You. The 2nd library solved my problem and is very easy to implement.

Comment: hey Jameson, Can i also send audio stream using Ghedeon's library? I have tried it but this gives error: "Stream close" can you help me with that?